# QGIS Python Programming Error - Build Virtual Raster (.vrt file) - Error : Unable to execute algorithm Wrong parameter value :

Tags: qgis, error, gdalbuildvrt, qgis-python-console

I am reading a single row from a text file createvrt_row0.txt. The row is :

```
E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E2.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E3.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E4.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E5.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E6.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E7.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E8.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E9.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E10.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E11.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E12.tif;
```

Python code which I used in QGIS Python Console for reading this single line in the text file is :

```
data = open('E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/output/task/createvrt_row0.txt', 'r')
```

Now, I deleted the last " ; " by doing :

```
data_str = str(data)
data_vrt = data_str[:-1]
```

So, now :

```
data_vrt = E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E2.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E3.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E4.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E5.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E6.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E7.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E8.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E9.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E10.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E11.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E12.tif
```

Then, I want this data_vrt string inside double quotes (" ").

```
TIF_files = '"' + str(data_vrt) + '"'
```

So, now :

```
TIF_files = "E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E2.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E3.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E4.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E5.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E6.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E7.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E8.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E9.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E10.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E11.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E12.tif"
```

This TIF_files string is used as the input file for the tif files which have to be finally converted to a single .vrt file in QGIS. For that I used the following python code in QGIS Python Console.

```
output_vrt = "E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/output/outvrt.vrt"
from processing.tools import * 
general.runalg("gdalogr:buildvirtualraster",TIF_files,0,True,False,output_vrt)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error in Python Console as :

```
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: "E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E2.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E3.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E4.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E5.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E6.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E7.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E8.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E9.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E10.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E11.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E12.tif"
```

Because of this error, I am not getting the output .vrt file.

But. I just tried copying this tif files and assigned this to a variable x as given below :

```
x = "E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E2.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E3.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E4.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E5.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E6.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E7.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E8.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E9.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E10.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E11.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E12.tif"
```

Now, when I try to run the python code, the output .vrt file is getting generated successfully.

```
general.runalg("gdalogr:buildvirtualraster",x,0,True,False,output_vrt)
```

But, when I am trying with "TIF_files" instead of "x" , I am agian getting the error. Actually, both "TIF_files" and "x" have the same string. This is really confusing and I am not able to solve the error "Wrong parameter value:".

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Try with data_vrt, perhaps it is known to be string already.

Comment: @user30184 But, I want data_vrt inside double quotes (then only the syntax will be correct for general.runalg().). That's why I tried with TIF_files = '"' + str(data_vrt) + '"' . Also, when I tried doing like TIF_files = '"' + data_vrt + '"' (by considering that data_vrt is known to be a string already), still I am getting the error.

Comment: What we know is that x works but TIF_files does not work so they cannot be equal. And if you test by `x="test" print x` vs. `y='"' + str(x) + '"' print y` you will see that with the syntax you used for x the double quotas are not included in the string.

Comment: @user30184 When I tried giving data_vrt directly inside the algorithm, it worked and the issue is solved now. general.runalg("gdalogr:buildvirtualraster",data_vrt,0,True,False,output_vrt) . The algorithm automatically creates double quotes on both sides of data_vrt when we give that variable as an input inside the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of giving double quotes on both sides of data_vrt .

```
TIF_files = '"' + str(data_vrt) + '"'  // No need of this statement in my program.
```

It is possible to directly give data_vrt (without any double quotes) as input into the algorithm.

```
general.runalg("gdalogr:buildvirtualraster",data_vrt,0,True,False,output_vrt)  // This will solve the issue.
```

The algorithm automatically used double quotes on both sides of data_vrt and executed the program successfully.

Remember,

```
data_vrt = E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E2.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E3.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E4.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E5.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E6.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E7.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E8.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E9.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E10.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E11.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E12.tif
```

But, if we assign this input into a variable x, then we have to use double quotes on both sides of the list of tif files.

```
x = "E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E2.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E3.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E4.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E5.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E6.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E7.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E8.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E9.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E10.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E11.tif;E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/1 deg tiles_Global agri_data/N31E12.tif"
```

So,

```
general.runalg("gdalogr:buildvirtualraster",x,0,True,False,output_vrt)
```

will also work.

The main point is data_vrt is a line which is directly taken as an input from a text file in the computer. So when we execute data_vrt inside algorithm directly without using double quotes on both sides, program will work perfectly.

But, if we copy this list of tif files and assign into a variable x as given above, then we must use double quotes on both sides of the list of tif files.

This solves the issue perfectly. Thank You.